# why eclipse running my project on apache 8080 by default

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am running my maven project on tomcat using eclipse. But don't know why its running it on 8080 port as Tomcat7 installed is running on 8081 port. I don't know how to change it.

I am running my project like

```
  right click on my project -> run as -> Run Configuration -> Write "${workspace_loc:/myapp}" in Base directory-> Goal "tomcat:run"> then click Run

   then it shows "[INFO] Running war on "http://localhost:8080/myapp". Its by default running on my tomcat 6.0 server which is running my other applications.
```

I have even changed target runtime to Tomcat7 and even tried change the goal to tomcat7:run.

Please let me know if you need any further information

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html.

Comment: Yes, I upvoted your comment :)

Comment: I don't understand why my question is down voted? what not clear from my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat server configuration has it's listening port to `8080` by default. You can find the configuration in `server.xml` located in `conf` directory and change the port if you like.

It would look like

```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Change the port attribute as you like. If you want to change the port in eclipse embedded `tomcat` server, then Open the `Servers` and browse the configured tomcat directory listed in it. You will see `server.xml`. Change the port in it and re-run `mvn`

As said by @Gimby, I really the missed the point. But, still the port settings in server.xml is also a place for problems. Try deleting the server configuration and recreate in eclipse and check the correct port is mentioned.

If everything is mentioned correct, I think you need to set this property

`maven.tomcat.port` to `8081` like

`mvn tomcat7:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081`

That may solve the problem

Comment: You miss the point of the question; the key is "as Tomcat7 installed is running on 8081 port". I read the question as: I have two tomcats, one running on 8080, one running on 8081, when I deploy my application it goes to the 8080 one and I don't know how to change it so the 8081 one is used.

Comment: Hi Octopus, tomcat 6.0 is running on 8080 port and tomcat 7 is running on 8081 port I want to run my application on tomcat7.

Comment: Thanks for better explanation Gimby

Comment: Cool Octopus, mvn tomcat7:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081 this is working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to double click in the server list view of eclipse (where you see all your configured servers in eclipse), so it will open a tab with the configuration options of the server, there you will see one to set the server ports, change the HTTP port.

Comment: Check the server that is responding is not one of the other servers with tomcat 6 you say you have :P. Stop tomcat7 and start tomcat 6 and viceversa, and try.